# Is UDP losing part of my packet here?

Tags: java

Im trying to send a packet back to the user informing them of all the people currently on the server, when they send a message to the server which has the word "who" in it.

Here is my code:

```
else if( response.contains( "who" ) )
{
     System.out.println( "Size of names collection: "+names.size() );

     buf = null;
     buf = names.toString().getBytes();

     int thisPort = packet.getPort();
     packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length,packet.getAddress(),thisPort );
     socket.send(packet);
}
```

The output of the print statement above is 2 indicating that there are two people on, for example andrew and james. Now when I package it up and send it I would expect it to output this:

[Andrew, James]

But instead the client gets:

[Andrew,

And thats it. Whats the problem? BTW I have to use UDP for this and can't switch to TCP

***UPDATE***

Here is the code in the client class that receives the packets:

```
 while( true )
        {
            try
            {
                // Set the buf to 256 to receive data back from same address and port
                buf = null;
                buf = new byte[256];
                packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, 4445);
                socket.receive(packet);

                String response = new String( packet.getData() );

                // Receive the packet back
                System.out.println( response );
            }
            catch( IOException e )
            {

            }

        }
```

Comment: I think you just posted half of your question there

Comment: Are you saying this always happens or only sometimes and in random ways?

Comment: always happens. I tried storing all the names as a string - each time a new person joins the name is concerted to the original string. I even tried doubling the size of the buffer array and still nothing!

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the client?

Comment: I have added the client code which receives packets above

Comment: Im at the stage of trying anything here so I decided to try a long shot and run it on a different IDE - guess what - same result >:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your datagram is being truncated to 256 byes because that's the size of the buffer you declared for the receiving DatagramPacket. If your datagrams can be longer, make the buffer bigger.

Best practice is to make it one bigger than the largest datagram you are expecting to receive. Then if you receive one that size you have an application protocol error.

Comment: Thanks mate it works now. Im thinking that, in order to combat the protocol error, I'll create a method to log the size of the latest packet received and then set the receiving buffer to 513 bytes more than the one logged - what you think? Also why was the packet being truncated?

Comment: @Katana24 Because that's what it says it does in the Javadoc: "If the message is longer than the packet's length, the message is truncated". The datagram arrived intact via UDP but then Java or more probably the Sockets API had to truncate it to squeeze it into your 256 bytes. Hard to see what else it could do.

Comment: Understandable - but collections such as array list must be a lot bigger than their string counterparts then - because I manually created a string with the same names and such in them and sent them over and there were no problems.

Comment: @Katana24 I cannot make head or tail of that statement, but a byte[] array has a fixed size declared by you: no power on earth is sufficient to change its size if it's too small.

Answer (score 1):

You should check on both client and server the length of the DatagramPacket after the send/receive operation respectively (with the getLength method) to make sure it's the same, that would be the first hint. What Collection are you using for *names*?

Comment: Im using an array list, do you know the answer? If so please tell me :P been spending all day obsessing over this!

Comment: Ok - I checked it. In the server code the length of the packet sent is, for two clients 1026. When the packet is received the packet length is 256. What the heck is happening here?

Comment: I see you got your answer from @EJP, just two remarks on the client: the packet.getData() just returns the buffer you gave in the constructor, so you may just as well call  new String(buf) instead; second, creating a byte array each time you receive a packet is kind of a waste if you're expecting high traffic, so maybe you should reuse the same DatagramPacket, it will still work. Cheers!

Comment: `new String(buf)` is not correct. It should be `new String(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength())` in full generality.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete. However..

UDP loses packets. That's why it's not reliable to use UDP for File Transfer purposes. The Adobe RTMFP uses UDP to transfer audio and video data in which many packets are lost., But audio/video content streaming is really faster when compared to TCP. I don't know if this answers your question, I just want to say that UDP does lose packets.

Comment: Recheck my post - and yes Im aware of that

Comment: However, it doesn't lose parts of packets.  If a packet arrives, it is intact.